# Draw multiple arrows

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, drawing

There used to be a feature in the drawing tools of Microsoft Office that you double click a drawing tool (such as arrow) and that meant you'd draw that and your next click would draw the same of that over and over again until you right click or press escape or something.

That seems gone. Is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do this in current versions of Office is to right-click on the shape and choose "Lock Drawing Mode".

[image: screenshot]