# Use same colour/format when drawing multiple shapes in a row

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a load of images and would like to draw arrows between them. Lock Drawing mode lets me do many arrows in a row. How can I lock the format (line width & colour) to save me going back and selecting them all individually to reformat?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1052702/draw-multiple-arrows

Answer (score 1):

To set the default shape line-width and color,
select the model shape, right-click the border, and then click
"Set as Default Shape" on the popup menu:

[image]

These defaults will stay in force until you change them again
in the same way.

Comment: Ok not ideal this persists indefinitely but fine. Is there an easy way to reset to the default if I don't remember what it was before?

Comment: Good question - there doesn't seem to be any such option. But you may use a shape created before this as defaults by using again "Set as Default Shape" on it.

Comment: FWIW, setting a default as described sets it for the current presentation. Each presentation can have its own set of defaults.  If you don't like that approach, you can use the format painter.  Draw your shapes, set the formatting of one shape the way you like it, then while it's selected, on the Home tab | Clipboard group, DOUBLE-click the paintbrush icon. Then click any other shape you want to apply the same formatting to. You can change slides and keep clicking if you like. Press ESC to stop applying formatting.